# Error with g++47 make compilation?

Tags: g++

> ~/cddir>ls
>
> hw1            machine.cpp  main.o      makefile~     report2.txt   user.cpp
>
> hw11submit.sh  machine.h    makefile    report1.txt   report2.txt~  user.h
>
> hw12submit.sh  main.cpp     #makefile#  report1.txt~  soda.x
>
> ~/cddir>make
>
> make: *** No rule to make target `g++47', needed by`machine.o'.  Stop.

All of my files are there and they ran perfectly before. Now I re-log in and get this error. A day yesterday on Google didn't help, but maybe I am looking in the wrong place.

Makefile:

```
soda.x: main.o machine.o user.o                                                 
        g++47 -osoda.x main.o machine.o user.o                                  

user.o: user.h user.cpp                                                        \
        g++47 -c -Wall -Wextra -I. user.cpp                                     

machine.o: machine.h machine.cpp                                               \
        g++47 -c -Wall -Wextra -I. machine.cpp                                 \

main.o: main.cpp                                                                
        g++47 -c -Wall -Wextra -I. main.cpp
```

E-macs env.

Comment: Can you paste your makefile and your environment?

Comment: @schaiba fixed.

Comment: What's the output of 'which g++47' ?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/g++47

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have trailing `\` in your Makefile. They shouldn't be there, that makes `make` think g++47 is one of the pre-reqs.

Just remove the backslashes. (And make sure the compile lines start with a tab.)

Comment: I can't remove the backslashes. It won't let me @Mat!

Comment: Maybe you have very long lines and the backslashes are displayed by your editor to signify line-wrap. Try inserting a newline after `user.cpp`.